# Action Script class vs Action Script File in Adobe Flash Builder

Tags: flash, flash-builder

I can see two options are Action script File and Action Script Class in File -> New from menu.

What is different between Action Script File and Action Script Class whether both are identically same or not?

Most of scenario i used Action Script Class only so i would like to know when we have to go for Action Script File?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action script File and Action Script Class as both *.AS files.

The only difference is that the Class will generate all the package/class/constructor code for you while a File - won't.

If you wander why is an AS file is needed:

- Sometimes you don't want pre-generated code
- You might face with AS files of earlier AS versions
- It might be just done as another option just to have. Mostly you'll be choosing AS Classes or Interfaces anyway.

In short - there's no particular reason

Comment: You do affirm it does not exist but obviously without knowing if it does or not. include is of course available in as3 as well and works the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Actionscript class files contain one class which has the same name as the file itself (other classes can be hidden along). Actionscript files are simple collection of code lines which can then be used anywhere even inside classes using:

```
include "myasfile.as"
```

Also class files have a scope while actionscript files do not. You cannot move a class file around in your project without having to update its namespace (package path), an actionscript file does not have this restriction since it does not belong to any scope per say.